# Error "no such element: Unable to locate element"

Tags: java, selenium

I am on this page

https://login.alibaba.com/?spm=a2700.8293689.0.0.NdeZUw&tracelog=hd_signin

And trying to access Email field by following web element code:

```
public static WebElement Email_Field(WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException {

        //element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions
                //.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='fm-login-id']")));

        element = driver.findElement(By
                .xpath("//input[@id='fm-login-id']"));

        while (!isDisplayed(element)) {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            System.out.println("Element is not visible yet");
        }

        return element;
    }


public static boolean isDisplayed(WebElement element) {
        try {
            if(element.isDisplayed())
                return element.isDisplayed();
            }catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

But getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='fm-login-id']"}
  (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)
```

Comment: Consider updating the HTML DOM. Thanks

Comment: Your error tells you about element `.//*[@id='fm-login-id']` but I can see `//input[@id='fm-login-id']` in your code. Why is there a difference?

Comment: The information he seek is in the `iframe` - perhaps the frame loads afterward. Consider waiting for the DomReady event etc. Consult your web driver API

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The email field is inside the frame. Before access any element in the frame, you have to switch. please try following code.

```
public static WebElement Email_Field(WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException {

    WebElement element;

    (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("alibaba-login-box"));

    element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='fm-login-id']"));

    while (!isDisplayed(element)) {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        System.out.println("Element is not visible yet");
    }

    return element;
}
```